# How to iterate in order for a custom map?

Tags: c++

I am looking to build my own map class. (Which will behave exactly like the C++ STL) I want to be able to iterate through all the elements in order by key value.

I implemented my map as an unbalanced binary search tree.

So my question is how to do an iterator increment efficiently. One inefficient way is to iterate through every single element in the tree to find the next lowest key. Is there a faster way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on the implementation details. If the nodes of your unbalanced binary search tree have a "parent" pointer, you could use that to traverse it. Your implementation of ++iterator could look a bit like this:

```
if (current_node.has_right_child()) {
  // We go to the right subtree of the current node and
  // take the smallest element of that subtree.
  current_node = current_node.right_child();
  while (current_node.has_left_child()) {
    current_node = current_node.left_child();
  }
} else {
  // We have to go up. If the current element is the left child of the parent,
  // we can just go to the right child of the parent.
  // If it is the right child, we have to go further up
  while (true) {
    if (!current_node.has_parent()) {
      // We got up to the root and never found a right child.
      // So we are at the end of the iteration.
      current_node = NULL;
      break;
    }
    Node* parent = current_node.parent();
    bool is_left_child = parent.left_child() == current_node;
    current_node = parent;
    if (is_left_child) {
      // if this was the left child, then the parent is the correct next element.
      break;
    }
    // if this was the right child, we have to go further up
    // until we leave this subtree, so we continue iterating.
  }
}
```

If your binary tree does NOT have parent nodes, you could store the parents in the iterator. I.e. you could maintain a vector parents; in which you store the parents of the current node up to the root. If this is still needed, I can provide an implementation, but because you edited my "non parent pointer" version with parent pointers, it seems that you have parent pointers. So I leave it away.

Comment: Thanks, but I think part of the answer is wrong in the case when the node does NOT have a right child.
Example: Insert 10, 3, 7,, 6, 100, 50, 2, 9, 50, 60, 30, 20, 400)
After node holding 30, we should get 50. But this implementation will give me 60.

In the case that there is a right child, it will work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I modified the code of the first implementation. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: No, I think that your edit was completely incorrect. You also mixed the version without parent pointers with the version with parent pointers. I assume that means you do have parent pointers. I am sorry, I just wrote the solution down in a few minutes without thinking about it. Now it should be better.